# フォームに入力された内容によって画面遷移先を変更したい

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, thymeleaf

私はSpring Boot + Thymeleaf + MySQLで開発を始めたばかりです。

フォームに入力された内容によって画面遷移先を変更したいのですが、うまくいっていません。

例えば、入力フォームに「1」(DBのID)と入力されたら、
http://localhost:8080/edit/1
に遷移したいです。

初歩的な質問ですみませんが、回答お願い致します。

◆ソースコード

[html]

```
   <form method="post" action="/edit">
    <h1>Please input the number</h1>
    <input type="text" name="id" th:value="${id}" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send" >
    <br>
    <a th:href="@{/}">Back enter display</a>
    </form>
```

[コントローラ]

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/edit/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView edit(@ModelAttribute MyData mydata, @PathVariable int id, ModelAndView mav) {
        mav.setViewName("edit");
        mav.addObject("title", "edit mydata");
        mav.addObject("id",id);
        Optional<MyData> data = repository.findById((long)id);
        mav.addObject("formModel",data.get());
        return mav;
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/edit/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    public ModelAndView update(@ModelAttribute MyData mydata,@PathVariable int id, ModelAndView mav) {
        mydata.setId(id);
        repository.saveAndFlush(mydata);
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/searchId", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView searchId(@ModelAttribute("formModel") MyData mydata, ModelAndView mav) {
        mav.setViewName("searchId");
        return mav;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/searchId", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView serachId(@PathVariable int id, ModelAndView mav) {
        mav.setViewName("searchId");
        return new ModelAndView("'/edit");
    }
```

[エラー内容]
入力フォームに「1」と入力して「Send」ボタンを押すと、
URLは「http://localhost:8080/edit」となり、
エラーメッセージは以下が表示されます。

```
--
 Whitelabel Error Page
    This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

    Wed Oct 09 19:26:41 JST 2019
    There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
    No message available
--
```

ブラウザでURLに直接
http://localhost:8080/edit/1
と入力した場合は、正しく画面遷移することは確認できています。

どのように修正したらよいか、教えてください。

Answer (score 0):

```html
   <form method="post" action="/edit">
    <h1>Please input the number</h1>
    <input type="text" name="id" th:value="${id}" />
```

となっているので、ボタンをクリックすると、`/edit`というパスに対して、リクエスト・パラメーター`id`がPOSTで送信されます。なので、`@RequestMapping`の値が`"/edit"`かつメソッドがPOSTで、`@RequestParam`を指定した`id`の引数を持つ以下のようなメソッドが必要だと思います。

```java
    @RequestMapping(value = "/edit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView update(@ModelAttribute MyData mydata, @RequestParam int id, ･･･
```

※動作確認しているわけではないので、間違っているかもしれませんが。